# Simple iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm in the process of the building a simple iphone application and I had a few questions.

I need to parse through results from an API key search, and manipulate them in my program. The API is from rotten tomatoes, and I can't find a parser that works with ARC. I know the JSON kit works well for previous versions of XCode, but I really like ARC and have done my application to date using it.

1) Is there a solid parser for such results or is it something I'm going to have to do manually?

The basic structure of my app includes a search page and personal list of things, using a mutable array of objects to populate a table view.

2) whats the best way to design the classes and implementation? I know this is a vague questions so let me be more specific. I have one object with several attributes, and I want to both access a remote server and rotten tomatoes API, and store local data internally. So I have my storyboad with a controller for each tab view (there are two). Then I have my object class. Do i need to create a controller specifically for it or can I manipulate (create and delete) in other controllers?

I can give some more specifics about the application, I'm just feeling a little overwhelmed as it is my first time working with Xcode. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May i suggest you the [NSJSONSerialization Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)., it should work well with ARC as it is compatible with `iOS 5` and above.

Or you can set the `ARC` flag to no in `.m` files that you would like it to be switched off. For that purpose you can refer a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658549/876283).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a compiler flag on the implementations that aren't going to be used in ARC.

Use: **`-fno-objc-arc`**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, you can turn ARC off on specific files, this allows you to mix ARC enabled with non-ARC enabled classes in the same project,
Please refer to the answer of this question
[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

About the second question
Do you have two different classes that access the same api services?
If yes i suggest that you create a common remote-request class, this class will do the request for you.

For example:
Let say we have class1 (for tab1) and class2 (for tab2)
And we have classCommonRequest(for both the requests)
App delegate will hold a reference to the classCommonRequest

class1 and class2 can both access this class by using

```
YourAppDelegate *delegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//get your refrence of request handler class
MyRequestHandler *request = [delegate myRequestHandler];
//then use functions in it
[request fetchSth];
```

If your question was more specific i could give you better answers :)
I hope this helped anyway